# How should I use the "in-", "im-", "il-", and "ir-" prefixes?

Tags: prefixes, neologisms

Consider the following words:

> ***im**possible*;
>   ***in**correct*;
>   ***im**patient*;
>   ***il**legal*;
>   ***ir**regular*;

The meaning of the prefixes is the same (negation the adverb), but they are still different prefixes.

How do I know which one to use? In other words, *for an arbitrary adjective*, how do I choose between *"in-"*, *"im-"*, *"il-"*, and *"ir-"*?

The [relevant discussion at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33903/rule-to-determine-when-to-use-the-prefix-im-vs-un-to-negate-a-word-starting) does not provide with any guideline.

Comment: *Irregardless* of these rules pay attention not to double the negative by using both a negative prefix and negative suffix.

Comment: @SF. correct, and also some stems are confusing: "important", "industrial"

Comment: Also *"en-"* and *"em-"*, especially but not exclusively in words derived from Latin via French, e.g. "inquire" versus "enquire".

Comment: The meaning of the prefix is negation in your examples; but it can also mean **in**, as in *innate*, *impersonate*, *illuminate* and *irradiate*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Formally, it is the same prefix *"in-"*.
However, there are four different spellings that help pronunciation.

The rule only depends on the first letter of the adjective:

> **L** — use *"il-"*: ***il**legal*, ***il**literate*;
>   **P**, **M**, or **B** — use *"im-"*: ***im**proper*, ***im**mediate*, ***im**balance*;
>   **R** — use *"ir-"*: ***ir**responsible*, ***ir**rational*;
>   other consonants or vowels — use *"in-"*: ***in**different*, ***in**numerable*, ***in**adequate*;

Comment: +1 It's possibly worth adding that these uses are all adopted from or extensions of the practice in Latin, from which the prefix is borrowed, along with many of the words.

Comment: I've never heard (or seen) "innatural"; "unnatural" is what I would expect.  Webster's 3rd Unabridged shows fewer than four columns of "in-n*" words, and fewer than five of those words are negative, "innumerable" being the most familiar.  For most, the "in" supplies the sense of "inherent". (However, if an "in" prefix is appropriate -- for negation or innateness -- the "n" should definitely be doubled.)