# Why is it "inerrant" instead of "unerrant" when the definition is "something that is unerring?"

Tags: adjectives, american-english

While searching for the correct spelling of inerrant, I came across a definition that labeled it as something that is unerring.

Why would something that is unerring be "inerrant" instead of "unerrant?"

Comment: "in-" (as meaning "not")  is the Latin cognate to "un-". Also shows up in *illegal, immune, impossible, irregular, irresponsible, inexcusable, indirect, inept, inert, incompetent*, among some others.

Comment: I don't think this question is about etymology and word origins. This is a legitimate question that a user could ask as English is not consistent in placing prefixes. "Unhappy" vs "inhappy", "uncorrect" vs "incorrect", "unimportant" vs "inimportant".

Comment: I agree with @Rathony. The ***answer*** to a question shouldn't make the ***question*** off-topic.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Negation prefixes: un- or in-?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/61727/9161)

Comment: Some of your confusion may be because although they are spelled similarly, [to err](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/erring) is different from being [errant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/errant). They both have some Latin roots, but come from different words in Middle English.

Comment: I can't think of any context where ***inerring, inerrant*** or ***unerrant*** wouldn't be better replaced by ***unerring***. The "reason" why ***in-*** and ***-ant*** have lost out to ***un-*** and ***-ing*** here is essentially just a matter of established idiomatic preference. But that preference is so strong you don't really even need to think about those ultra-rare / obsolete alternatives.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but inerrant means 'incapable of erring/infallible', not necessarily 'committing no mistakes/consistently correct'. Besides it always makes me think of knight-errant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could find, the word "unerring" came into use in 1640s  from *un*-"not" + verbal noun from *err* (from Old French errer - "go astray, lose one's way; make a mistake; transgress").

The word "inerrant" came into use in 1650s, in reference to "fixed" stars (as opposed to "wandering" planets), from Latin *inerrantem* - "not wandering, fixed (of stars)", from *in-* "not, opposite of"  and present participle of Latin *errare* ("to wander, stray, roam, rove").  Its usage as "unerring, free from error" began from 1785.

So,  although the two words may be of the same origin (from Latin), they [came into the English usage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=inerrant) separately, each one by its own way.

Comment: Well, ultimately they are of the same origin; but the point is that one of them was formed in English from a Latin root, the other formed in Latin and taken over via French into English. Notice that "erring" already has English material in it ('-ing'). But there's no way to know in advance which negative words were taken from Latin or French, and which were formed in English: that's a historical accident.